# Casting to a java object in Mozilla Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, birt, rhino

I'm wondering is there a way of casting a Java object in Rhino? I would usually do this in Java by doing the following:

```
List<Object[]> mylist = myServiceClass.getList(id);
for (Object[] object : myList) {

  Apple a = (Apple) object[0];
  // do something    
}
```

But in Rhino, I'm not sure. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried:

```
apple = myList.get(i)
```

And:

```
apple = (Packages.com.package.fruits.Apple) myList.get(i);
```

I keep getting the error

```
Java class "[Ljava.lang.Object;" has no public instance field or method named "getColour" when trying to access the apple object.
```

Comment: [Is this what you're after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial#expose)? More context from your Rhino code might be useful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast in javascript. But you need to call the method on the correct object. The error message states that you call the method on an Object[] (The [ before L gives that away).

To get the first object from Object[] before you call getColour() on it

`myList.get(i)[0].getColour()`